# Updated Rich Text save action - can I force all Rich Text fields to resave?

Tags: richtext-editor

I have updated some code to modify the way Rich Text fields handle the rel="nofollow" tags. the change occurs when the Rich Text field is saved. This works fine for new content. But for existing content... How can I resave all Rich Text fields? Is that even possible? Could this be done directly in SQL?

Comment: Powershell? (loop through all your relevant items and save them)

Comment: Is your code executed on item:saving or some other event? or what do you mean by "when the rich text field is saved"?

Comment: I bailed on this method. I'm making my changes in the render field pipeline instead.